# Copy files in powershell according to the date modified

Tags: powershell, archive

I'm trying to copy files in a folder to another folder according to the date modified but the code keeps copying all files in the source folder to the destination folder.

```
New-Item -Path $psScriptRoot\ArchiveTest -ItemType Directory 

compress-Archive -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.txt -DestinationPath $PSScriptRoot\ArchiveTest  | Where-Object LastWriteTime -Like "*2010*"
```

I've tried changing the Syntax of the where-Object cmdlet. When I use the Get-Item cmdlet with the exact same Where-Object i get the correct output.

The end goal is to archive the files in a folder according to year, so for instance:

Items in folder:

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

---

-a----        2010/02/15     15:23          39590 Test5.txt
-a----        2010/02/24     17:43         690581 Test5.txt
-a----        2012/04/12     11:46         105086 Test5.txt
-a----        2015/05/10     15:46       15952531 Test5.txt
-a----        2015/05/12     09:27         453365 Test5.txt

What I want to end with in the folder:

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

---

d-----        2023/01/10     11:35                2010       -----
d-----        2023/01/10     11:35                2012       ------- (Zip Folders)
d-----        2023/01/10     11:35                2015       -----/

Comment: Your order is wrong, you first need to get the files and filter them by the properties you want. After that you can pipe them into the `Compress-Archive` Cmdlet. First, use the `Get-ChildItem` command to get your files, pipe them into your `Where-Object` and lastly pipe that into the `Compress-Archive`

Comment: I understood this so wrong, I see now that the | is used to pipe into teh next command so it seems this works : Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\*.WS | Where-Object LastWriteTime -Like "*2010*"  | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $PSScriptRoot\Archive

Comment: I just added an example on how to do it as an answer, hope it helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Yes, that is how the pipe `|` works in powershell, it is always front to back in order. If you have more complex tasks which you can't fit on a single line you will have to write a .ps1 or .psm1 file. If you come to a point where you have to write script file, I'd recommend not using the Pipe at all if possible as it makes the code more unreadable.

Comment: How would I do it differently if I used a script? I want to make a script I can copy into a folder, run and it archives everything in the folder according to year.

Comment: Take the second code I provided, write it into a `.ps1` file and execute it. You could also change the script so that all sub-folders are gathered first. You then loop through the sub-directories and check the files. That way you only need a single script in one directory and you don't have to copy it anywhere.

Comment: I will probably do that as well, not a bad idea. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I tried to do that so i don't have to copy it but i think I'm just messing it up. Should i start a new thread, or should i post it on this one?

Comment: What part did you mess up?
You can get all sub-directories this way: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Filter "*.txt" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq "2022" } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$PSScriptRoot\archive_2022.zip"
```

Here is how to do it in a loop for several years:

```
$startYear = 2001;
$endYear = 2020;

for ($year = $startYear; $year -le $endYear; $year++) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Filter "*.txt" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$PSScriptRoot\archive_$year.zip"
}
```

Comment: Got about the same but your format looks a lot better. Thank you so much. Is there a way to loop this through all years since 2001 to 2020?

Comment: @FrancoisB I've just updated my answer, it now includes the loop

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with is:

```
    $StartYear = 2001;
    $EndYear = 2021;
    $Thickness = @(Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot |
                 Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
                 ForEach-Object {$_.Name})
    
    Write-Output $Thickness
    
    for($Counter=0;$Counter -lt $Thickness.Count;$Counter++) {
        if(!(Test-Path -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$($Thickness[$Counter])\Previous Years")) {
               new-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$($Thickness[$Counter])\Previous Years" -ItemType Directory
        }
        for ($year = $startYear; $year -le $endYear; $year++){
            Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\$($Thickness[$Counter]) -Filter "*.WS" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$PSScriptRoot\$($Thickness[$Counter])\Previous Years\$year.zip"
            Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\$($Thickness[$Counter]) -Filter "*.WS" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $year } | Remove-Item
        }   
    }
```

Any comment on how i could improve it?

Comment: Improve in what way? Performance, less folders, all folders in a special directory?

Comment: improve in syntax and performance

Comment: StackOverflow is rather for issues with code and general questions. For improvements and feedback I'd recommend posting it on CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com